# Обновление данных в RecyclerView с помощью RecyclerView.OnScrollListener

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, recyclerviewadapter

Проблема в том, что при выполнение нового запроса на сервер после прокручивания у меня список полностью обновляется, необходимо, чтобы он добавлялся к прошлому. 
Я думаю мне нужно как-то в HomePresenter смотреть, если уже есть данных, то добавить новые. Не могу понять как это сделать, только начал изучать и пробывать MVP (Или это проблема в адаптере?)

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements HomeView{


    @BindView(R.id.recyclerView)
    RecyclerView recyclerView;

    HomePresenter presenter;

    private static int offset;

    private static boolean isLoading;

    public static void setIsLoading(boolean isLoading) {
        HomeActivity.isLoading = isLoading;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        presenter = new HomePresenter(this);
        presenter.getData(offset);
        offset = 0;
        isLoading = true;
    }


    @Override
    public void setData(List<PokemonData.Pokemon> pokemons) {
        RecyclerViewHomeAdapter homeAdapter = new RecyclerViewHomeAdapter(pokemons, this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(homeAdapter);
        GridLayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2, RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerViewOnScroll() {
            @Override
            protected void loadMore() {

                if (isLoading) {

                    offset+=30;
                    presenter.getData(offset);
                    isLoading = false;

                }
            }
        });
        homeAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
```

HomePresenter:

```
public class HomePresenter {

    private HomeView view;


    public HomePresenter(HomeView view) {
        this.view = view;
    }

    void getData(int offset) {

        Call<PokemonData> pokemonDataCall = Utils.getApi().getData(offset, 30);

        pokemonDataCall.enqueue(new Callback<PokemonData>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<PokemonData> call, Response<PokemonData> response) {

                HomeActivity.setIsLoading(true);

                if (response.isSuccessful() && response.body() != null) {
                    view.setData(response.body().getResults());

                }
                else {
                    view.onErrorLoading(response.message());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<PokemonData> call, Throwable t) {
                HomeActivity.setIsLoading(true);
                view.onErrorLoading(t.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: нужно проверять, если данные уже есть, то их нужно дополнить, а не заменить, и проблема уйдет.

Comment: Пройдите вот эти курсы по пагинации и проблема уйдёт: https://startandroid.ru/ru/courses/architecture-components/27-course/architecture-components/542-urok-14-paging-library-chast-1.html. Или делайте так как вы это сделали, но добавьте вот это: https://startandroid.ru/ru/blog/504-primer-ispolzovanija-android-diffutil.html. Не изобретайте лошадей, их изобрела природа.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если кому-то поможет решение, необходимо было вынести всю инициализацию из метода setData.

```
    public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements HomeView{


    @BindView(R.id.recyclerView)
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    @BindView(R.id.btn_refresh)
    FloatingActionButton btn_refresh;

    HomePresenter presenter;
    private List<PokemonData.Pokemon> items = new ArrayList<>();

    private static int offset;

    private static boolean isLoading;
    private RecyclerViewHomeAdapter homeAdapter;

    public static void setIsLoading(boolean isLoading) {
        HomeActivity.isLoading = isLoading;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        presenter = new HomePresenter(this);
        presenter.getData(offset);
        offset = 0;
        isLoading = true;

        homeAdapter = new RecyclerViewHomeAdapter(items, this);

        recyclerView.setAdapter(homeAdapter);
        GridLayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2, RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerViewOnScroll() {
            @Override
            protected void loadMore() {

                if (isLoading) {
                    offset+=30;
                    presenter.getData(offset);
                    isLoading = false;
                    homeAdapter.setPokemonList(items);
                }
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void setData(List<PokemonData.Pokemon> pokemons) {
        items.addAll(pokemons);
        homeAdapter.setPokemonList(items)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю использовать DiffCallback, создаёшь диф класс, в одном методе необходимо прописать поля, по которым старый и новый объект считаются, одним и тем же побъектом, во втором методе, определяешь состояние каких полей может измениться, чтоб этот объект должен был быть изменён в адаптере.
Вот статься на медиум https://medium.com/@iammert/using-diffutil-in-android-recyclerview-bdca8e4fbb00
Или погугли примеров довольно много.